# onload attribute doesn't work in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts, onload, struts-1

I'm executing an internal script (and external scripts), using `<script>` inside `<head>`.

I'd like to execute some JavaScript after the document has been "loaded".

I put a "onload" attribute inside the body :

```
<body onload="myFunctionName();">
```

I call the function with the "onchange" attribute inside the jsp (inside `<html:select ... >` struts tag) :

```
onchange="javascript:myFunctionName();"
```

The "onchange" attribute works but not the "onload" attribute. Why ?

Comment: Are you getting any error in console ?

Comment: No error in console..

Comment: Please post your code so we can find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

My code is working here !

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunctionName();">

    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">

   function myFunctionName(){
        alert('I am here!');
    }

    myFunctionName();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunctionName();">
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function myFunctionName(){
        alert('I am myFunctionName!');
    }
</script>
```

But good practice is to separate javascript from html.

Comment: I have updated my answer please let's have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because HTML 5 doesn't support the onload attribute. (`<!doctype html>`)
I use a shortcut

by detecting an error of an image.
Here is an example that you can just copy&paste:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Your Title</title>

  <head>

    <body>
      <img src="noSrc" alt="" onerror="myFunction()">

      <!--This img tag and all the attributes are mandatory or else it will not work-->

      <script>
        function myFunction() {
          //code here
          document.write("Document Loaded."); //example
          window.alert("Document Loaded");
        }
      </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Good Luck!!